# Parse a PHP string with PHP parser

Tags: php, string

I wanted to ask whether I'm doomed to use `eval()` or there may be a work around.

```
$str = 'Hello, $user.'; // $str is a string gotten from an external source

// Many lines later

$user = 'John Doe';

echo eval('return "'.$str.'";');
```

Not a big fan of `eval`, as probably many of you. Is there another way to parse a PHP string?

Comment: If you not fan of [`eval()`](http://php.net/eval) maybe [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf) is an option?

Comment: `str_replace('$user', $user, $str)` ?

Comment: @FDL, wel that was just for the sake of the example. Obviously the variable will not always be `$user`

Comment: Will the replacements always be simple variables? How much PHP do you have to support in it?

Comment: @Barmar yes, but I was wondering if I could use php to parse it, instead of writing regular expressions, because, you know, the guys from PHP will certainly do it better than me

Comment: If it's just simple variables, you could use `preg_replace_callback`, searching for `\$\w+`, and replace it with the value of `$_GLOBALS[$match[0]]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with:

```
$str = 'Hello, $user.';
$data = array(
    'user' => 'John Doe'
);

$output = preg_replace_callback('/\$(\w+)/', function($key) use ($data) {
    return isset($data[$key[1]]) ? $data[$key[1]] : $key[1];
}, $str);

var_dump($output);
```

Output:

```
string 'Hello, John Doe.' (length=16)
```

Comment: I just did some benchmarking, with 1 replacement both `eval` and `regex` perform relatively equally fast, however if I add more variables `eval` becomes times faster. I guess I'll have to stick with it, unfortunately..

Comment: Well if I put an `addslashes` inside, since I have surrounding quotes, I guess it should be ok, no? `eval('return "'.addslashes($str).'";');`

Answer (score 2):

You can try `create_function`. It doesn't execute just any piece of code, but wraps it in a function. Apart from that, it's not that different.

But if your goal is to replace variables alone, you might want to have a look at the `str_replace` function. That will work fine for a fixed set of variables. If you want to be more flexible, you can use `preg_replace` or `preg_replace_callback`, but note that a 'flexible' function is probably a function that allows you to use any variable. That also allows people to exploit that feature to read variables that they are not supposed to read.

Comment: This function internally performs an eval() and as such has the same security issues as eval().

Comment: RegEx`es is the way, probably. Any other attempts will anyway lead to `eval()` at sometime.